# VS2019 custom template - parent variable prefix (ext_) not working

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to create a custom template for VS2019 comprised of multiple projects (based on [this](https://blog.jayway.com/2015/03/13/visual-studio-how-to-create-a-solution-template-with-multiple-projects/) guide), and I'm having problems with the references.

My solution is based on the classic 3-tier architecture (data/business/ui), so when I create a new solution - call it "MySolution", I get "MySolution.Data", "MySolution.Business" and "MySolution.UI" - all good. I need the business layer to have a reference to the data layer - however, using the `$ext_safeprojectname$` variable just gives me an unresolved reference in the projects node of my dependencies to "$ext_safeprojectname$.Data"

Other variables seem to work fine - for example, if I use `$safeprojectname$`, I get "MySolution.Business.Data" in my reference - correct parsing of the variable, for the business layer project, but not the desired result.

Has the `ext_` prefix been replaced? I cannot seem to find any documentation for this anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ben, I am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it after commenting on your question. I was missing the `CopyParameters=true` attribute for `ProjectTemplateLink` element in the `.vstemplate` file. It is mentioned as a tip on [Create a multi-project template from an existing solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019#create-a-multi-project-template-from-an-existing-solution). My `ext_` variables were replaced once I did this. Your `ProjectTemplateLink` element should look something like below:

`<ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyProject" CopyParameters="true">...</ProjectTemplateLink>`